# Change App Bar Background Color

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm struggling to override the default themes app bar color properly.
When I use the android:actionBarStyle it changes the color but then the title text is missing.

```
<resources>
  <style name="ToolbarThemeStyle" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTitle.Background</item>
  </style>
  <style name="ActionBarTitle.Background" parent="">
    <item name="android:background">#8DC44E</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitle.Text</item>
  </style>
  <style name="ActionBarTitle.Text" parent="">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

I've tried [Replacing the Action Bar](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/toolbar/part-1-replacing-the-action-bar/) but I'm wondering if there's not a shorter and easier way.

**Manifest:**

```
<application android:label="Home Automation" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light"    
  </application>
```

**Activity:**

```
[Activity(Label = "Label", MainLauncher = false, Theme = "@style/ToolbarThemeStyle", NoHistory =true)]
```

Comment: ActionBar actionBar;
     actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.alert_vehicle);

Comment: use this drawable like create custom xml layout

Comment: Take a look at this link you will definately come to know your problem

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your replies. I thought I'd answer this myself whereas I've spent hours trying to figure this out.

The obvious solution was in [this page](http://No%20resource%20found%20that%20matches%20the%20given%20name%20(at%20'android:color%20Primary')) under Using Custom Themes but I was getting the error *"No resource found that matches the given name (android:color Primary)"*. Changing `android:minSDKVersion=23` also did not work.

I went to Application Properties and set the "Compile using Android version" to the current targeting framework (i.e. API 23) instead of the maximum which was not installed yet set to API 25.

Answer (score 0):

make sure are you setting theme to activity in menifest or xml. Here I am sharing my theme code you can refer.

```
 <style name="MaterialAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/red</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: My default theme is in Manifest. I'm overriding the app bar by setting Activity Theme to XML. Your code gives Error: No resource found that matches the give name: attr 'colorPrimary'

Comment: @Jnr I read your comments. This is right, which compile SDK you have declared.It should be installed.

Answer (score 0):

This code should  be in you style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

And make sure  you should have declared it in manifest.xml

```
<application
        android:name=".app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/images"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: Please see my update. I get the same errors as in @vishal answer's comment.

Comment: please paste you error let me see it and you have not pasted the same code which I have given in the answer

Comment: I think you must take a look at this link

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

Comment: I already read a similar post here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html

Comment: The link which I have given is not same as as yours in the link which I have given there is complete code given so you can correct your mistakes from there

Comment: In android developer link which you have given there is not everything explained so have a look at the link which I have given